# Async Task crashing on backbutton pressed.

Tags: android, android-asynctask

What happens to an async task when the calling fragment is paused/removed? I am assuming that the task completes but it would be great of someone can just confirm that. I am trying to find a fix to my crash.

I have an async task that is a recursive image loader. The image loader is an inner class of the listFragment that it loads images for. The image loader works perfectly unless i press back button before it has finished loading all the images. When i press the back button before all the images are done loading the application crashes. I feel like the image loader loses access to the adapter but I am not sure if i am attacking this problem correctly. I am unsure of how to fix this issue within my async task. If someone could help me out. Even bounce an idea off my head to get me thinking differently.

Any help would be awesome. Thankyou for your time to even look.

ImageLoader

```
private class ImageLoaderTask extends
        AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(
            HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {
        InputStream in = null;

        String url = (String) hm[0].get("image");
        int pos = (Integer) hm[0].get("pos");
        url = "http://kzfr.org/u/img/small/" + url;
        URL mUrl;

        try {
            mUrl = new URL(url);
            URLConnection urlConnect = (URLConnection) mUrl
                    .openConnection();
            in = urlConnect.getInputStream();

            File cacheDirectory = getSherlockActivity().getBaseContext()
                    .getCacheDir();

            File tmp = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/kzfr_small"
                    + pos + ".png");

            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(tmp);

            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

            HashMap<String, Object> hmBmp = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hmBmp.put("blank_start", tmp.getPath());
            hmBmp.put("pos", pos);
            return hmBmp;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
        // this is the img path that leads to a local image that was just
        // saved on the phone.
        String imgPath = (String) result.get("blank_start");
        // the position of the image in the listview
        int position = (Integer) result.get("pos");
        // local adapter
        SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) getListAdapter();
        // hashmap entry from the local adapter at the position of the image
        // that we just loaded.
        HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter
                .getItem(position);
        // replace the actual blank image with the image path that we just
        // loaded
        hm.put("blank_start", imgPath);
        // update listview
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // we are done with the current position increment position and move
        // on.
        position++;
        // this while loop finds the next position in the adapter that does
        // not have false for an image path. False indicates that there is
        // no image and i should load a default image.
        while (position < adapter.getCount()) {
            hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);
            imgPath = (String) hm.get("image");

            if (!imgPath.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                break;
            }
            position++;
        }

        // checks to make sure that the position is not out of bounds on the
        // adapter. If in bounds then there might be more images to load.
        // Start a new ImageLoader. This is a recursive Class.
        if (position < adapter.getCount()) {
            ImageLoaderTask imageLoader = new ImageLoaderTask();

            hm.put("pos", (position));
            imageLoader.execute(hm);
        }

    }
```

StackTrace

```
01-14 20:09:28.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6069): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 20:09:28.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6069): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 20:09:28.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6069):     at com.appdomum.doublea.ListFrag$ImageLoaderTask.onPostExecute(ListFrag.java:272)
01-14 20:09:28.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6069):     at com.appdomum.doublea.ListFrag$ImageLoaderTask.onPostExecute(ListFrag.java:1)
01-14 20:09:28.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6069):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
01-14 20:09:28.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6069):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
01-14 20:09:28.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6069):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
01-14 20:09:28.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6069):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 20:09:28.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6069):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-14 20:09:28.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
01-14 20:09:28.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 20:09:28.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-14 20:09:28.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6069):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-14 20:09:28.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6069):     at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-14 20:09:28.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6069):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: which line is 272?  It's likely that you'r etrying to reference something that isn't there anymore because the activity has finished()

Comment: line 272 is `String imgPath = (String) result.get("blank_start");` out of onPostExecute.  That is referencing something that should be internal to the Image Loader class because it is passed from the DoIn Background.

Comment: you should check that result.hasKey("blank_start") first. it looks like there is no item for that key so its returning null.

Comment: I dont think it is the lack of item in that key because the error only occurs when i cancel the async task before it finished loading everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're on the right track here.

When writing custom `AsyncTask`s many developers forget, that it is necessary to handle task cancellation. Simply cancelling the task doesn't mean that its code won't execute on (for example) `Activity`/`Fragment` resources, that might be freed up at the time. This is typically done in these steps:

1. After creating a task, save a reference to it.
2. Cancel all running tasks after `Activity`/`Fragment` is finished. This is typically done in `Activity.onDestroy()`/`Fragment.onDestroy()`. Remove all references to cancelled tasks.
3. In task's code:

   1. In `doInBackground()` periodically check if it `isCancelled()`. If so, tidy up and abort further execution.
   2. Eventually handle cancellation in `onCancelled()` (runs on UI thread).
   3. Perform any handling of cancelled task in `onPostExecute()` (which *is executed* with a `null` result if the task was cancelled).

Comment: So number 3 there explains the null result in `onPostExecute()` Because when i press the back button the fragment gets removed. I am not using show/hide because i have had too many issues with it that i am unable to track down.

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly the information i needed explained in a way that makes sense of what i was dealing with. Thankyou andr. I am off to implement.

Comment: Exactly, but there may be more causes for NPE or other errors if a task executes after Fragment/Activity is destroyed. Just be cautious :) Oh, and remember that you still can add breakpoints in `onPostExecute()` (for example) and watch variable values in `Variables` tab. That sometimes helps *a lot*.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens to an async task when the calling fragment is paused/removed? I am assuming that the task completes but it would be great of someone can just confirm that.

That is incorrect; the framework does not do the work for you by canceling work you are doing in background threads.  The reason callbacks like `onPause()` and `onResume()` are called is to notify your application that ***you*** need to clean up and cancel any running work that is not in a long-lived component like a `Service`.

In this case, if you don't cancel the task is continues to run.  Since this class is defined as a non-static inner class, it also means you've created a temporary memory leak because the `AsyncTask` is holding an implicit reference to the `Fragment`, and since the task is attached to a running thread neither object (or their members) can be garbage collected even after `onDestroy()`.

You need to implement your `AsyncTask` in such a way that it will check for the cancel flag you can manually cancel the work from `onPause()` or a similar callback.